# React form in Modal dialog for both create and update

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, mui-x

I am trying to create a Modal dialog with a form for both create/update in my React MUI application.

I have created the form in a reusable component with it's own context.

Context Stuff:

```
const SystemFormContext = createContext<
  | {
      openSystemDialog: (props: SystemFormProps) => void;
      closeSystemDialog: () => void;
      isDialogOpen: boolean;
      dialogProps: SystemFormProps;
    }
  | undefined
>(undefined);

export function useSystemFormContext() {
  const context = useContext(SystemFormContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      'useSystemFormContext must be used within a SystemFormProvider'
    );
  }
  return context;
}

export function SystemFormProvider({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  const [isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dialogProps, setDialogProps] = useState<SystemFormProps>(
    {} as SystemFormProps
  );

  const openSystemDialog = (props: SystemFormProps) => {
    setDialogProps(props);
    setDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const closeSystemDialog = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
    setDialogProps({} as SystemFormProps);
  };

  return (
    <SystemFormContext.Provider
      value={{ openSystemDialog, closeSystemDialog, dialogProps, isDialogOpen }}
    >
      {children}
    </SystemFormContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Modal Component:

```
const SystemFormModalDialog: React.FC = () => {
  const { closeSystemDialog, dialogProps, isDialogOpen } =
    useSystemFormContext();
  const { title, dto, onConfirm } = dialogProps;

  const formVals = dto || defaultValue;

  const { handleSubmit, control, setError, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: formVals,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: ISystemConfigDto) => {
    onConfirm(data, setError, reset);
  };

  return !isDialogOpen ? null : (
    <Dialog open={isDialogOpen} onClose={closeSystemDialog}>
      <DialogContent>
        <IconButton
          size="small"
          onClick={closeSystemDialog}
          sx={{ position: 'absolute', right: '1rem', top: '1rem' }}
        ></IconButton>
        <Box sx={{ mb: 8 }}>
          <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
          {/* <Typography variant='body2'>{subtitle}</Typography> */}
        </Box>
        <Grid container spacing={6}>
          <Grid xs={12}>
            <MyInput
              {...{
                name: 'name',
                label: 'Name',
                control: control,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12}>
            <MyInput
              {...{
                name: 'code',
                label: 'Code',
                control: control,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12}>
            <MyInput
              {...{
                name: 'description',
                label: 'Description',
                control: control,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions
        sx={{
          justifyContent: 'right',
        }}
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mr: 1 }}
          onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={closeSystemDialog}
        >
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default SystemFormModalDialog;
```

Then for example purposes I am launching the modal dialog for both create/update in the page.tsx component

```
const handleOpenSystemModalDialog = (action = 'create') => {
    let dto = null;

    if (action != 'create') {
      if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length == 1) {
        dto = rows.find((x) => x.id == selectedRows[0]);
      }
    }
    console.log(rows, action, selectedRows, dto);
    openSystemDialog({
      title: `${dto ? 'Update' : 'Create'} Renewal Type`,
      onConfirm: onSave,
      dto: dto,
    });
  };
```

Now, even though the `dto` is being passed to the modal dialog in `openSystemDialog ()` and I can see the values updating in the Modal dialog component - they are not showing up in the Input components.

What am I doing wrong that the inputs are always blank in the form modal dialog?

A working example can be found here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uigmbn?file=src%2Fpage.tsx

I would expect when clicking the Create button the form to be blank, but when clicking update (because the dto is being passed in) that the form to retain the dto values.

#### UPDATE

---

I used the `reset(dto)` from react hook forms to set the dto in a `useEffect()` hook to get this working. Not sure if this is the right aproach at the moment - so including it part of the question

```
const SystemFormModalDialog: React.FC = () => {
  const { closeSystemDialog, dialogProps, isDialogOpen } =
    useSystemFormContext();
  const { title, dto, onConfirm } = dialogProps;

  //  const formVals = defaultValue;

  const { handleSubmit, control, setError, reset, setValue } = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultValue,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // setValue('name', dto?.name)
    //  setValue('description', dto?.description)
    //  setValue('code', dto?.code)
    //  setValue('id', dto?.id)
    reset(dto || defaultValue);
  }, [dto]);
```